# Help in understanding a property of Lebesgue measure and linear applications.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, linear-transformations

I've been trying to understand why this relation is true and can't find the right way to attack it.

Let $\Phi$ be a  linear map from $R^d$ to $R^d$ and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure in $R^d$, then for all E measurable set:

$$ \lambda( \Phi (E))= |(det(\Phi))|*\lambda(E)$$

According to my textbook, this should easily lead to the known formula of integration by variable change.

Démarche:
I consider the characteristc function of $\Phi(E)$:
if for $b$ its equal to 1 then $$\exists a\in E \Rightarrow \Phi(a)=b [1]$$ and the characteristic function of $E$ in $a$ is 1.
Since, $$\lambda(\Phi (E))=\int characteristicfunction(\Phi( E))(x)$$ $$\forall x \in R^d $$
Now, I know that [1] implies: $$det(b)=det(\Phi)*det(a)$$
Is this enough to prove that:  $$\int characteristicfuntion(\Phi(E)) = \int characteristicfuntion(E)*det(\Phi)$$

Comment: For an introduction to using mathematical notation here, see [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on MathJax and $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Do you want to understand why this formula is true (its usually proven by directly proving it for a generator of ${\rm Mat}_d(\mathbf R)$) or how this "easily" leads to the known formula for integrals?

Comment: I want to know why the formula is true.

Comment: I already got to the other one by simply accepting it as true, thank you.

Comment: everything you added is hard to understand. e.g. if $a∈ E$, how can you take its determinant?

Comment: Yes,
A and B are both matrices in $R^d$ space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For intuition, you can think of the SVD of $\Phi$, which is $\Phi = U \Lambda V^*$, where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal and $\Lambda$ is diagonal with nonnegative diagonal entries.  Note that $U$ and $V$ have no effect on Lebesgue measure, while $\Lambda$ simply performs a component-wise scaling, which has the effect of multiplying the measure by $|\text{det} \Lambda | = |\text{det} \Phi |$.  A rigorous proof based on this intuition appears in the book [Mathematical Analysis:An Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387946144) by Browder.

Comment: I can see how this relates to the determinant equailty and why neither U or V will have effect on the measure, but I don`t see how it gives a proof of the first formula.
If I take your $Λ$ how do I now know that it works?
Thank you.

Comment: You can see that if $E$ is a rectangle, then the measure of $\Lambda E$ is $| \text{det} \Lambda |$ times the measure of $E$, because the rectangle just gets stretched in each dimension.  And if $E$ is not a rectangle, but is filled up with tiny nonoverlapping rectangles, you can see what happens to the measure of each tiny rectangle, which tells us what happens to the measure of $E$.  This is just an intuitive argument, not rigorous.

Comment: Yes, I've been over it with a colleague and your argument is right, I can now see it. The wikipedia gif also helped: [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Singular_value_decomposition.gif)
Thank you @littleO !